# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI SpringMVC Rest APi

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets

I am a beginner user of Spring Framework. I am trying to create a simple Spring MVC project using Eclipse IDE and to deploye it on Apache Tomcat but I get the following error in terminal:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/FirstSpringProject/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'manaf'
```

Webbrowser show 404 error(http://localhost/FirstSpringProject/)

this is my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<display-name>FirstSpringProject</display-name>
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>manaf</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>manaf</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/welcome.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/welcome.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

this is my manaf-servlet.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.manaf.controller.*" />
<bean id="viewResolver"
 class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
<property name="viewClass"
 value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

this is my controller

```
package com.manaf.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public ModelAndView testMethod()
{
    String msg="Haai brothers";
    return new ModelAndView("welcome","message",msg);
}

}
```

Comment: Add ` <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`

Comment: where have you kept your `index.jsp` and `default.jsp` in your project?

Comment: after adding <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> issue not solved

Comment: Move it outside your `WEB-INF` folder.

Comment: iam just moved index.jsp to outside folder. its working. but i cant go to welcome.jsp page its placed on web-inf folder

Comment: what url you are hitting?

Comment: http://localhost/FirstSpringProject/  --> it is working                   http://localhost/FirstSpringProject/welcome.html

Comment: Then include .html in your RequestMapping like `@RequestMapping("/welcome.html")`.

Comment: Sep 09, 2015 3:22:27 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/FirstSpringProject/welcome.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'manaf'

Comment: Just include `<mvc:annotation-driven />` in your `manaf-servlet.xml`.

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
The prefix "mvc" for element "mvc:annotation-driven" is not bound. manaf-servlet.xml /FirstSpringProject/WebContent/WEB-INF line 10 XML Problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `web.xml` edit manaf servlet mapping as below:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>manaf</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>manaf</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Edit your `manaf-servlet.xml` as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.manaf.controller" />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

Now, assuming you have **`index.jsp`** at `src/main/webapp/index.jsp`, you can access it using url : http://localhost/FirstSpringProject/ and assuming you have **`welcome.jsp`** at `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/welcome.jsp`, you can access the same using url : http://localhost/FirstSpringProject/welcome

Comment: Hi, i need to convert this project to REST API(REST Server) . I need diffrent types of results from api's(Json, Xml, plaintext).  any idea

Comment: It's a good article : https://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/java-ee/producing-and-consuming-json-or-xml-in-java-rest-services-with-jersey-and-jackson

Comment: i have a REST Server(writen in core java using jax-rs). actually i need to convert it to spring framework.